# Microsoft SQL Server Case Does not return from subquery while it works in db2

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, db2

I am writing a sql query which runs fine for Db2 but its giving error when i run against Sql server database engine.

Here is the query.

```
select sum(number1 + number2) from (
    select 
        case when column1 = -1 then 3 else column1 End as number1,
        case when column2 = -1 then 3 else column2 End as number2
        from table1 where id=1
)
```

Its giving the following error when i run it against Microsoft SQL server using Squirrel as database client. I have also tried to run it directly on Sql server using its management studio, but still no luck.

> Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
>
> SQLState:  S0001
>
> ErrorCode: 156

I believe its the syntax issue. We have to do it some other way in Sql server.

Any help would be appreciated. I have spent a day trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: You don't even have 'SET' in the code you included... but you at least are missing an alias for the derived table

Comment: Yes you are right. It means its some other issue. And as far as alias thing, its not necessary and its working in db2.

Comment: It might not be necessary in db2, but it is necessary in SQL Server

Comment: tried with alias even now, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, derived tables need to have a table alias:

```
select sum(number1 + number2) from (
    select 
        case when column1 = -1 then 3 else column1 End as number1,
        case when column2 = -1 then 3 else column2 End as number2
        from table1 where id=1
) t;
```

Or, with the full alias syntax:

```
select sum(number1 + number2) from (
    select 
        case when column1 = -1 then 3 else column1 End as number1,
        case when column2 = -1 then 3 else column2 End as number2
        from table1 where id=1
) AS t (number1, number2);
```

Comment: @UmairKhalid Didn't you just say that you tried it with alias and it didn't work?

Comment: @JamesZ I would guess he used an alias in the wrong spot.

Comment: @JamesZ yes i use alias name at the wrong place just after the first select. Sorry.